# Installed xubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 16.04, now things are broken

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce

I was running Ubuntu 16.04 with defaults (lightdm, Unity).

I desired to switch to Xubuntu, and did an `apt install xubuntu-desktop`, as well as `apt-purge ubuntu-desktop unity-*`.

I can log into XFCE now but I have several problems:

- Xfce will not launch gnome-terminal as its default, even after setting it via `update-alternatives`
- There's half a broken settings bar on the top with incomplete settings. If I access the proper Xfce settings from the left menu, those are fine.

[image: screenshot]

I don't know why this section of the top bar is differently colored, and it has a duplicate battery indicator, date/time, settings that don't quite work. How can I remove it?

Thanks.

*edit*

Those original problems are solved.

- I was missing the `apt auto-remove` to clean up the old settings
- Xfce has a settings page called "Preferred Applications" where I was able to set up gnome-terminal as the default
- The little black section of the top bar is called the Indicator Panel, and it's a known issue that it doesn't match the regular color scheme

Now I have 2 other strange issues after a day of Xfce:

- When I wake up from sleep, and start typing my unlock password, the screen will flash once, within a second of the unlock, and mess up the password I typed. I need to wait for the flicker to pass to type my password without errors
- My keyboard doesn't work immediately after unlocking. I need to perform an action with my mouse. E.g. if I unlock and press `Ctrl+Alt+T` to launch the terminal, nothing happens. If I type in my browser to open a new tab, nothing happens. If I minimize a window with my mouse, then my keyboard starts working again.

Comment: Have you run update and upgrade commands?

Comment: Actually it looks like autoremove fixed the top bar issue. But I haven't managed to get gnome-terminal to replace xfce-terminal yet. I can just create a different shortcut for it but I really want to know how to override `TerminalEmulator`

Comment: Oops, totally missed the "Preferred Applications" option.